# Align paper-icon-button to end in top-right of scaffold

Tags: html, css, polymer

Have...
[image]

```html
<core-scaffold id="core_scaffold">
    <core-header-panel mode="seamed" id="core_header_panel" navigation flex>
        <core-toolbar id="core_toolbar"></core-toolbar>
        <core-menu valueattr="label" id="core_menu" theme="core-light-theme">
            <core-item id="core_item" icon="settings" label="Item1" horizontal center layout></core-item>
            <core-item id="core_item1" icon="settings" label="Item2" horizontal center layout></core-item>
        </core-menu>
    </core-header-panel>
    <div id="div" tool>Title</div> <span flex tool></span>
    <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" id="paper_icon_button" tool></paper-icon-button>
</core-scaffold>
```

Need...
[image]

Tried align end on the button and inserting a
`<span tool flex></span>` [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lg_hE5tIfwY).

[Demo site](https://www.polymer-project.org/tools/designer/preview.html#efc7f0ee524d1ab8d6c3).

Comment: isn't there some CSS code you can add?

Comment: Then the css tag is a bit irrelevant, isn't it?

Comment: Can the css properties be removed?i.e. if you remove the properties for the id #paper_icon_button, this should solve the issue.

Comment: yes, it was just the removal of css on that item

Answer (score 2, accepted):

button had style of

```
#paper_icon_button {
    left: 610px;
    top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

needed to be

```
#paper_icon_button {
    position: relative;
}
```

*realizing now these styles could have been changed from the designer...
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I've found this from some docs:

```
<div horizontal end-justified layout>
  <div>end-justified</div>
</div>
```

maybe this can help

source: https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/layout-attrs.html

Comment: helpful, was expecting it to just be an attr tag. that div does get end-justified, but not when applied to the paper-icon-button

Comment: well editing the css it what i had to do. was just hoping it could have been done with the polymer designer or with a html attr. it's good.

Answer (score 1):

If you insert the `flex` attribute inside the `title` div and remove the unnecessary empty `span` you achieve your intended result.

*Using Polymer-0.5*

```html
<core-scaffold id="core_scaffold">
  <core-header-panel mode="seamed" id="core_header_panel" navigation flex>
    <!-- ... -->
  </core-header-panel>
  <div id="div" flex tool>Title</div>
  <paper-icon-button icon="more-vert" id="paper_icon_button" tool></paper-icon-button>
</core-scaffold>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your title wants the "title" css class. It will push your menu button to the right. Take a look at https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-toolbar/blob/master/paper-toolbar.html